# Crispy stir-fried mushrooms

Tags: mushrooms

How do you prepare mushroom pepper fry? I wanted it to be crispy, but the mushroom itself was generating lot of water. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Recipe questions are off-topic for this forum: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking/1313#1313 I'd suggest re-asking a more general question about how to fry mushrooms so that they're crispy.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27713/how-to-properly-saut%C3%A9-mushrooms-so-that-they-dont-release-water

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mushrooms typically release water if they are overcooked and also if salt is added too early in the cooking process.

When cooking mushrooms, cook them on a relatively high heat until they have just developed some colour. at the end of the cooking process add your seasoning.

Answer (score 5):

also- don't crowd them.  put them in your hot pan, in a single layer, with space inbetween the mushrooms.

let them sit a while, then stir them up a bit, then let them sit a while, then stir a bit.